# PostgreSQL UPDATE JOIN runs forever

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following query:

```
UPDATE cards
SET tags = array_append(c.tags, 'accident')
FROM cardaccidents
INNER JOIN cards c ON cardaccidents.event_id = c.event_id;
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to append text 'accident' into `tags` in table `cards` where it has a respective `event_id` in the `cardaccidents` table. Probably I do it in unoptimal way, because it takes very long (I've never waited for more than 7 minutes) to execute this query. However, the same `JOIN` without `UPDATE` executes in a split second (16ms).

How can I speed up this query (or probably rewrite it)? What causes such difference in execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeating the `cards` twice.  That is not how Postgres works.

Try this:

```
UPDATE cards c
    SET tags = array_append(c.tags, 'accident')
FROM cardaccidents ca
WHERE ca.event_id = c.event_id;
```

In Postgres, the reference to `cards` in the `UPDATE` and in the `FROM` are two separate references.  Hence, your query is updating *all* rows in `cards` -- and each row is being updated a zillion times, based on the product of the rows in `cards` and `cardaccidents`.

If your `SELECT` is fast, then I assume this version will be pretty fast with no need to add further indexes.